# Write to multiple json files

Tags: python, pandas

I currently creating multiple json files from each line of a data frame -

```
for i in df.index:
    df.loc[i].to_json('{}.json'.format(df['properties'][i]['displayName']), orient='index', indent=4)
```

I am trying to add a text to the start and end of each file.

I have tried the following -
I want to however add text to the start and end of each file. I have tried the following -

```
    lines = f.readlines()
    f.seek(0)
    f.write(f2.read())
    for line in lines: 
        f.write(line)
    f.seek(0,2)
    f.write('] }')
    f.close()
```

However this will add the text to the start (f2) fro the first file but not any others. The end text ( ]} ) is however added to each file.

Comment: This smells like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/1206096). Can you explain the context ?

Comment: `f.write('] }')` is a huge red flag: you are treating JSON as raw text rather than an encoding of an existing data structure. Build the *list* you want, put that in a `dict`, then dump the entire `dict` to `f` in one shot.